# Jssor random transition

Tags: transition, jssor

Having 360+ transition effects is cool, but I have only 10 slides. How can I give them fancy transitions equal chance to show off? 
The transition effect is defined in `option` object before the JssorSlider object is created. It seems to me I can only pick 1 of the 360 and set it in the `option`. Can I have random transition effect for each transition?
A.K.A, after the `JssorSlider` is created, can I still apply new `option` values to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a transition array with multi transitions. And you can set $TransitionsOrder: 0 to let it play transition randomly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Define an array of slideshow transition code
    var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    { code1 },
    { code2 },
    { code3 }
    ];
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 0,    //The way to choose transition to play slideshow, 1: Sequence, 0: Random 
                $ShowLink: true
            }
    };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
});
```

After the JssorSlider is created, you can also set transitions dynamically by api call `$SetSlideshowTransitions(transArray)`.

```
jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions(transArray);
```

Reference:

http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html
http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html
http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html

Comment: Thank you! Can I change `option` settings after the `Jssor` object is created? For example, after the page loads, can I change `.$Options.$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions.$DisableDrag` from `undefined/false` to `true`, and in turn disable mouse dragging?

Comment: Once jssor slider is created, you cannot change any option.